# Exchange Online: Transport rules vs Quarantine policy

Tags: exchange-server, o365-flow, o365security-compliance

I would like to ask you for your help with Exchange configuration. We tried to set in O365 Exchange an transport rule/mail flow with following response action: "Deliver the message to the hosted quarantine". We noticed based on the MS documentation that Quarantine policies are not supported in transport rule (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/quarantine-policies?view=o365-worldwide) but then who is able to review/release the mails from quarantine? is it only Exchange admin / high privileges accounts? or is it possible to somehow configure it?

Also is there some recommended way how to bypass this limitation? e.g. set the mail via Transport rule as e.g.: high confidence spam or some other tag so other Threat protection would trigger and there set the quarantine policy on top those? or is there any other easier way?

Thank you!

Cheers,
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

Default Quarantine Policy

[image: 1]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/quarantine-policies?view=o365-worldwide

I have the same query. I found the above in Microsoft Docs which gives some hope but from what I have seen, there is no way to allow standard users to access items quarantined by Transport Rules or HCP.